# CSS Custom dropdown list modifies parent div height

Tags: html, css

I created a custom vuejs dropdown  component, my problem is that when the dropdown menu is displayed the parent div height increases and looks odd when this happens.

```css
.combobox-container{
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 5;
        top:0;
    }
    
    .combobox-list{
        position:relative;
        margin:0;
        max-height:154px;
        width:99%;
        background-color:white;
        overflow-y:auto;
        text-align:justify;
        border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
        top: 68px;
        right: 1px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.1em rgba(38, 47, 64, 0.25);
    }
    
    .combobox-option{
        padding:6px 13px;
        margin:0;
    }
    .combobox-option:hover{
        background-color:#d9d9d9;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="combobox-container">
        <div class="combobox-list">
            <p class="combobox-option">
            A
          </p>
            <p class="combobox-option">
            B
          </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div
```

How i can fix this? i played with `position:absolute` and `position:absolute` with combobox-container and combobox-list, and the result still the same.
**Note:** for further clarification i meant the  div container gets slightly bigger not combobox-container.

Comment: I tired your code, and I dont see the parent height being altered. Can you add a working code snippet?

Comment: @MattBunch i din't mean the element combobox-container but the parent div that contains combobox-container